# didDeselectItemAt indexPath doesn't triggered when another cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement this feature: in my app, if I selected a cell in UICollectionView, then the borders becomes blue, and if I select another one, the previous should be deselected and borders should become transparent. There is methods that I've written:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatCell

        /* Set some settings */
        if globalSelected[indexPath.item] {
            cell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        } else {
            cell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }

        return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Global variable for maintain selection
    global.selectedChatPath = indexPath
    globalSelected[indexPath.item] = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath != nilPath {
        globalSelected[indexPath.item] = false
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The ***nilPath*** is just ***IndexPath(item: -1, section: 0)***, but it doesn't matter, because ***collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)*** isn't even called. My CollectionView has *allowSelection = true* and *allowsMultipleSelection = false* properties. I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: add delegate for CollectionView "collectionView.delegate = self"

Comment: @Ragul Thank you! But it's already done: I have another class, which conforms UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols and I declared an instance of this class as delegate and datasource of my UICollectionView. Also, the first step works fine: after I click on any cell, the borders becomes blue (it means that the delegation works fine), but when I'm clicking the others, their borders become blue too, but the borders of the previous cells still blue (I want transparent).

Comment: just reload the collectionView for every selection

Comment: @Ragul in which methods? didSelectItemAt and DidDeselectItemAt are reloading my collection as I understand (they both contain collectionView.reloadData())

Comment: why would it be invoked? you reload the entire collection-view explicitly in the same runloop... iOS is not stupid to do a _deselect_ a row when it knows that it will _reload_ the entire collection-view anyway in the same loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only a single cell is supposed to be selected at the same time I recommend to put the currently selected index path into a instance variable (`nil` means nothing is selected)

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
```

In `cellForItemAt`set the colors depending on the instance variable

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatCell

    /* Set some settings */
    if let selected = selectedIndexPath, selected == indexPath {
        cell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    } else {
        cell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }

    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectItemAt` reload only the previous and new selected cells and set  `selectedIndexPath` to the new selected index path. This is more efficient than reloading the entire collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Global variable for maintain selection

    var cellsToReload = [indexPath]
    if let selected = selectedIndexPath {
        cellsToReload.append(selected)
    }
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: cellsToReload)
}
```

`didDeselectItemAt` is only needed if you want to deselect a cell explicitly.

Comment: This is the best solution so far. works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatCell

        /* Set some settings */
        if globalSelected[indexPath.item] {
            cell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
        } 
        else {
            cell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        }
        return cell
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
  if selectedIndex == indexPath.item {
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
  } else {
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
  }
}
```

and in didSelectItemAt,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  selectedIndex = indexPath.item
  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thank you! I've corrected my question (for now it contains cellForItemAt method too).

Comment: both your code and the collectionview is on a same controller?

Answer (score 0):

Reload your UICollectionView everytime a cell is selected and then change the border of the desired cell. 
When you reload data the border for the previous cell is removed, after which you can add border to the cell that you want.

Answer (score 0):

`didDeselectItem` won't be called until you tap the selected cell again. In order to deselect the previously selected cell when you tap another cell, you need to set the previously selected cell's setting in the global variable to `false` in `didSelectItem` like the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    globalSelected[global.selectedChatPath.item] = false //Set the previously selected cell's setting to false

    //Global variable for maintain selection
    global.selectedChatPath = indexPath
    globalSelected[indexPath.item] = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```